# How to create an object in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I want to create an object like the following

```
var obj = {
  'title1' : { 'sub-title':'subtitle1',
              'sub-content':'sub-content1'
             },
  'title2' : { 'sub-title':'subtitle2',
              'sub-content':'sub-content2'
             },

  'title3' : { 'sub-title':'subtitle3',
              'sub-content':'sub-content3'
             }
}
```

My js

```
obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        data.[i].title  //represent title1 , title2 and title3
        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].title.length; ++j) {
           data.[i].title[j].sub-title  //represent sub-title1 to sub-title3
           data.[i].title[j].sub-content  //represent sub-content1 to sub-content3
        }
}
```

I am not sure how to create an obj structure above. Thanks for the help!

Comment: the structure is wrong

Comment: is `data[i].title` an array?

Comment: What's `data` in this case?

Comment: there is no title in the Json

Comment: you are using `data[i].title` as a string to get `title1`, `title2` etc and also as an array in the `for` loop

Comment: use data[i] instead of data.[i]

Comment: @ArunPJohny and Jack you could answer the OP as he is showing var obj{....} example which is final result that wanted not seeing his tried js

Comment: @C-link  the `var obj = {...}` is the desired o/p, but since we don't know what `data` looks like it is impossible to guess an answer.. the main problem is the `title` it is used as a string and an array

Comment: I think he is using an array...

Comment: @C-link then what about the statement `data.[i].title  //represent title1 , title2 and title3`... here OP is suggesting it is a string which represent the target key of the data object in `obj`...

Comment: @C-link since OP is not responding and there is not enough info for an answer going to vote to close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  obj['title' + i] = {};
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    obj['title' + i]['sub-title' + j] = data[i][j].title;
    obj['title' + i]['sub-content' + j] = data[i][j].content;
  }
}
```

Just make some changes to adjust to the structure of the `data` object, but basically you can construct the desired object/output this way.

Answer (score 0):

Some modern browsers have support for parsing JSON into a native object:

var result = JSON.parse(obj);
you may then proceed as result[title1].sub-title and so on/

http://www.json.org/js.html

You may also check out json2.js(https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) which has alot of parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that working already? You are just trying to iterate the object using a wrong var called data.

Try using the loop like this:

```
for(var i in obj){
    var subObject = obj[i];
    console.log('---'+i+'---');
    for(var j in subObject){
        console.log(j + ": "+subObject[j]);
    }
}
```